# One image animate with left right button

Tags: jquery, html

as i click the left and the right arrow in the site the pictures are moving correspondingly ,but at the time i start clicking on the right arrow the picture is thrown out of the block limits.the normal animation pictures is 100 pixels but as i mentioned the issue above the program doesn't know the position of the pixels while we click the arrow fast.
i want you to inform or explain to me how this problem is fixed 
thank you

html code:

```
<div class="slider">
    <img src="http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-k__maLyJIPw/UWV1-WyW9rI/AAAAAAAAAJk/MVfNsKPQLsU/s1539/slider.png" alt="" />
    <a href="" class="left">left</a>
    <a href="" class="right">right</a>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
var left_animate = '+=100px';
var right_animate = '-=100px';

$('.slider .left').click(function () {

    var img_left_position = $('.slider img').position().left;

    if (img_left_position == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    $('.slider img').stop(true, true).animate({
        left: left_animate
    });
    return false;
});

var imgi = $(".slider img").width();

$('.slider .right').click(function () {

    var img_left_position = $('.slider img').position().left;
    if (imgi + img_left_position == 1600) {

        return false;
    }


    $('.slider img').stop(true, true).animate({
        left: right_animate
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AdTe/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gSwR/1/)

```
var newpos;
$('.slider .left').click(function(){
    var img_left_position = $('.slider img').position().left;
    newpos = img_left_position + 100 < 0 ? img_left_position + 100 : 0;  
    $('.slider img').stop(true,true).animate({
        left: newpos
    });
    return false;
});

var imgi = $(".slider img").width();
$('.slider .right').click(function(){
    var img_left_position = $('.slider img').position().left;
    newpos = img_left_position - 100 > -1600 ? img_left_position - 100 : -1600;
    $('.slider img').stop(true,true).animate({
        left: newpos
    });
    return false;
});
```